# What is the regular expression to get two numbers after a pattern in Solaris with a script?

Tags: regex, string, variables, solaris

I want a pair of numbers after a pattern in a line, the pattern is 'mt=' and its position is variable in the line, so if I have mt=83, I only want 83. 
I have the next code with an example of the line:

```
LINE=(10)un=5518666915/(34)ni=vvaummas03.me/ty=12/it=4/et=13/(8)id=ead57a5c/pt=7/to=20130408T155959Z/ot=2/(15)ed=ChangedGreeting/(16)ms=session_11218671/mt=81/

echo "$(expr substr $LINE $(($(echo $LINE | grep -b -o 'mt=' | cut -d: -f1)+4)) 2)"
```

I know the instruction can be improved, but it worked for me in CentOS, Cygwin and OpenSUSE, but when I run it in Solaris, the terminal show me that grep option -o and the -f1 instruction are invalid. I'm also having trouble with the instruction awk and another options like -c with cut; its very limited so I am searching for common commands on Solaris. I am not allowed to change or install anything on the system.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only a limited set of options it would be possible to do this using only Bash 3 or newer versions with regex matching:

```
if [[ "$LINE" =~ ^.*mt=([0-9]+).*$ ]]; then
    printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

This will capture any number with a least one digit, following the pattern `mt=` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
~]$ LINE="(10)un=5518666915/(34)ni=vvaummas03.me/ty=12/it=4/et=13/(8)id=ead57a5c/pt=7/to=20130408T155959Z/ot=2/(15)ed=ChangedGreeting/(16)ms=session_11218671/mt=81/"
~]$ echo $LINE | sed -e "s/.*mt=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/"
81
```

Comment: I tested it, in Cygwin it worked, but  in Solaris retrieved me the entire line, even I tested it outside the script as follows:  
echo "(10)un=5518666915/(34)ni=vvaummas03.me/ty=12/it=4/et=13/(8)id=ead57a5c/pt=7/to=20130408T155959Z/ot=2/(15)ed=ChangedGreeting/(16)ms=session_11218671/mt=81/" | sed -e "s/.*mt=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" and again, show me: 
(10)un=5518666915/(34)ni=vvaummas03.me/ty=12/it=4/et=13/(8)id=ead57a5c/pt=7/to=20130408T155959Z/ot=2/(15)ed=ChangedGreeting/(16)ms=session_11218671/mt=81/

Comment: That's odd, Solaris must have a different implementation of sed I guess.